# functions on sets proof (injective/surjective/bijective) question

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove the following three statements:

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets and let $f: A \rightarrow B$.

A. $f$ is one-to-one.

B. $f$ is onto.

C. $|A|=|B|$.

Prove that $(1)$ if A and B are true, then C is true, $(2)$ if A and C are true, then B is true, and $(3)$ if B and C are true, then A is true.

So far I have this:

(1). If $f$ is one-to-one, then for all $(x,b), (y,b) \in f$, $x=y$. If $f$ is onto, then for every $b \in B$ there is an $a \in A$ s.t. $f(a)=b$. This means that every value in the set $A$ maps to a distinct value in the set $B$. Thus, the sets have the same cardinalities, so, $|A|=|B|$.

(2). If $f$ is one-to-one, then for all $(x,b), (y,b) \in f$, $x=y$. And if $|A|=|B|$ then that means that every value of A maps to a distinct value in B. So, for every $b \in B$ there is an $a \in A$ s.t. $f(a)=b$, meaning $f$ is onto.

(3). If $f$ is onto, then for every $b \in B$ there is an $a \in A$ s.t. $f(a)=b$. And if $|A|=|B|$ then that means that every value of B must map to a distinct value in A. So, that means $f$ is one-to-one because there is no $(x,b),(y,b) \in f$ s.t. $x \neq y$.

But I don't know if I wrote enough for them?

Comment: At least for (2) and (3) it doesn't look like a proof to me.

Comment: I re-labelled your paragraphs as (1),(2),(3) to correspond to the Q's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempts at (2) and (3) are incomplete. Why? In (2) if $A$ and $B$ are not assumed to be finite the conclusion that $f$ is onto is invalid. How did you use the finiteness?

Suppose we assume that "$A$ is finite" means that there does  not exist a  one-to-one function  from $A$ to  a proper subset of $A$. Now $|A|=|B|$ implies there exists a bijection $g:B\to A$. So in (2) if $f$ is not onto then $(gf)$ is a one-to-one function from $B$ to a proper subset of $B$.